# Escape variable mysql password

Tags: mysql, bash, escaping

I have a mysql password that starts with a space. I want to put this password into a variable and then use it to connect in a bash script.

this works fine:

```
mysql -u me -p' examplepw'
```

but this does not:

```
pw=" examplepw"
mysql -u me -p'$pw'
```

because the single quotes make the variable name be interpreted literally (ie. mysql does not recognise the string `$pw` as a valid password).

How can I use a variable to hold a mysql password that requires escaping?

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`${}` expands a variable.

```
PASS=" 12345678"
mysql -u me -p"${PASS}"
```

In this case, `${PASS}` is extended to `12345678`

Comment: it does. but its so weird that works but `mysql -u me -p"$pw"` does not

Comment: actually cancel that last comment. `mysql -u me -p"$pw"` also works. that was the first thing i tried. must have had a typo :P

Comment: @mulllhausen, you are right. But, using `${}` to extend variable is safe. sometimes, we need to mix variable with others. like `"${VAR}SUFFIX"`, not `"$VARSUFFIX"`

Answer (score 1):

Ah I just found the solution: terminate the single quote, and concatenate the variable quoted with double quotes:

```
mysql -u me -p''"$pw"''
```

Comment: The single-quotes are not doing anything useful here; just remove them.

Comment: thanks man! the terminated single quotes here make it work. Any other combination has not helped for me to safeguard the password, but this works. The single-quotes help to safeguard passwords with special characters.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you're using environment variables, you could store the password in `MYSQL_PWD`. MySQL will just take it from there:

```
export MYSQL_PWD=" examplepw"
mysql -u me
```

Comment: You need to either `export` the `MYSQL_PWD` variable, or make the assignment a prefix to the `mysql` command (so it's only defined within that one command). Note that the prefix method is significantly more secure than exporting it to all programs run from that shell. It's also more secure than using the `-p` command-line option, because command arguments are considered public info, and will be viewable by e.g. `ps`. Environment variables are not.

Comment: Safety notice: *This method of specifying your MySQL password must be considered extremely insecure and should not be used. Some versions of ps include an option to display the environment of running processes. On some systems, if you set MYSQL_PWD, your password is exposed to any other user who runs ps. Even on systems without such a version of ps, it is unwise to assume that there are no other methods by which users can examine process environments.* Source: [6.1.2.1 End-User Guidelines for Password Security](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/password-security-user.html)

Comment: @Cyrus AIUI that exposure of environment variables only applies on some old Linus systems. Linux (and some other OSes) expose environment variables as /proc/[PID]/environ, but with permissions set so only the process owner can read it. If `ps` was SUID root, and read that without checking permissions itself, it could print all processes' environments. But I think that bug has been fixed for quite a while. In any case, it's better than passing the password as an argument, because those are viewable with `ps` on *any* unix-like OS.